Determining Bound States from Møller Operator
Hello I came across an interesting property of the Møller operator, which I summarize below:

The Møller operator $\Omega^{(+)}$ maps in-states that belong to the continuum spectrum of the free Hamiltonian $H_0$ into states that belong to the continuum spectrum of the exact Hamiltonian $H$. For potential scattering, $H_0$ has no bound states but $H$ may have them. If $\phi$ is a bound state of $H$ then $(\phi ,\Omega^{(+)} \psi^{(+)}) = 0$ for any in-state $\psi^{(+)}$.

Using the information given in the answer to my previous post, I tried to look for ways to prove it; however, I could not as I was not sure how the Møller operator acts on eigenstates of the full Hamiltonian (free particle + potential). Can anyone please explain why this property is true?

Is there a reference for the quote? Where does it come from?

If $H=H_0+V$, where $V$ is a so-called Kato potential, then the point spectrum of $H$ corresponds to the bound states, while the scattering states correspond to the continuous spectrum (Ruelle's theorem).
From the spectral theorem, we know that the Hilbert space decomposes as $\mathscr H=\mathscr H_p \oplus \mathscr H_c$, which means that bound and scattering states are orthogonal.
Since the image of $\Omega^{(+)}$ is in $\mathscr H_c$, the claim immediately follows.

References and further reading:

Ruelle, David. "A remark on bound states in potential-scattering theory." Il Nuovo Cimento A (1965-1970) 61.4 (1969): 655-662.

Sternberg, Shlomo. A mathematical companion to quantum mechanics. Courier Dover Publications, 2019. Chapter 18.

Amrein, Werner O. Hilbert space methods in quantum mechanics. EPFL press, 2009. Chapter 5.



Note: One might also prove more directly that the set of bound states is orthogonal to the set of scattering states, as shown in Ref. 2 and 3. (in general, care for the precise definitions). Then the only thing left to establish are conditions which ensure that the range of the relevant Møller operator is in the set of scattering states (and, well, its existence). In this answer here I tried to reflect the language in the question, which talks about continuous spectrum and bound states (instead of either scattering and bound states or continuous and point spectrum, for example).
